# Calculate running state in a database table

Tags: sql, mariadb

I would like to calculate the running event state (0 for stopped and 1 for running) for each row of a table of time-series events in MariaDB.

Given `id`, `start_event`, and `stop_event`, we must calculate `event_state`, which tells us if we are running or not.  We may get MANY redundant start or stop events, so only the most recent preceding one determines the current state.  The rules:

- The `event_state` is assumed to start at 0.
- If  `start_event` is 1 and `stop_event` is 0, then the current state is running (`1`).
- If `start_event` is 0 and `stop_event` is 1, then the current state is `0`.
- If `start_event` is 1 and `stop_event` is also 1, then we consider
  the state as stopped (`0`).
- If both `start_event` and `stop_event` are 0, then the current state is the same as the previous `event_state`.

Here is an example:

| id | start_event | stop_event | event_state |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 9 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 8 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 7 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 6 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Here is the table (with event_state already populated with the correct values; but your job is to replace those values once again.)

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table1`;
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
    `id` BIGINT,
    `start_event` BIT,
    `stop_event` BIT,
    `event_state` BIT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
INSERT INTO `table1`
    SELECT 10, 0, 1, 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 9, 0, 0, 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 8, 0, 1, 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 7, 0, 0, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, 0, 0, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 0, 0, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 1, 0, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 0, 0, 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 0, 1, 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 0, 1, 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 0, 0, 0, 0;
    
SELECT * FROM `table1` ORDER BY `id` DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**: Iterate over a cursor

This solution works but is very slow since it iterates over each row.

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS append_running_state;

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE append_running_state()
BEGIN

  DECLARE done BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE cur_id BIGINT(20);
  DECLARE cur_start_event BIT;
  DECLARE cur_stop_event BIT;
  DECLARE cur_event_state BIT;

  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
   (
       SELECT id, start_event, stop_event
       FROM table1
       ORDER BY `id` ASC
   );
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  SET cur_event_state = 0;

  OPEN cur;

  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO cur_id, cur_start_event, cur_stop_event;
      
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;

    IF cur_start_event = 1 THEN
      SET cur_event_state = 1;
   END IF;
    -- stop_event takes precedence; if both start = 1 and stop = 1, then it's a STOP.
    IF cur_stop_event = 1 THEN
      SET cur_event_state = 0;
    END IF;

   UPDATE table1
      SET event_state = cur_event_state
      WHERE id = cur_id;

  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;

CALL append_running_state();
```

**Solution 2**: Window function `LAST_EVENT() IGNORE NULLS`

Unfortunately, this slick solution is not currently supported by MariaDB as of August 2023 since:

1. MariaDB does not allow `IGNORE NULLS` on window functions.  See [support case MDEV-12984](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-12984) to track if this changes.  Or [use another database server](https://modern-sql.com/caniuse/last_value-ignore-nulls) that does support it.
2. Also, MariaDB doesn't allow window functions at all in UPDATE statements but this could overcome by using a temp table. (this is left as an exercise for the reader :) )

```sql
UPDATE table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   (
       SELECT 
           `id`,
           CASE
               WHEN (`start_event` AND (NOT `stop_event`)) THEN 1
               WHEN `stop_event` THEN 0
               ELSE NULL
           END AS event_signal
       FROM table1
   ) AS q
    ON q.id = table1.id
-- Find the last nonnull event signal
SET table1.event_state = LAST_VALUE(q.event_signal) IGNORE NULLS OVER (ORDER BY q.id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

**Solution 3**: Self-JOIN (the poor man's `LAST_VALUE() IGNORE NULLS`.)  This works and is fastest for now.

```sql
UPDATE table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
        WITH CTE AS 
        (
           SELECT 
               `id`,
               CASE
                   WHEN (start_event AND (NOT stop_event)) THEN 1
                   WHEN stop_event THEN 0
                   ELSE NULL
               END AS event_signal
           FROM table1
       )
       SELECT
        a.`id`,
        last_event.event_signal AS last_event_signal
        FROM CTE a
        LEFT JOIN CTE last_event
          ON last_event.id = (
               SELECT MAX(CTE.id) 
               FROM CTE
               WHERE CTE.`event_signal` IS NOT NULL AND CTE.id <= a.id
           )
       ) AS q
        ON q.id = table1.id
-- The last non-NULL event, or 0 if we are on the first row
SET table1.event_state = COALESCE(q.last_event_signal, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

We suppose that your `id` field is an auto incrementing value (even if not specified as such in question). In this case, "most recent preceding one" is a record with biggest `id` less then the current `id`.

When updating records with existing `id` field:

```sql
UPDATE table1
SET event_state = COALESCE(
  (SELECT t1.event_state
  FROM table1 t1
  WHERE t1.id < table1.id AND t1.event_state IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY t1.id DESC
  LIMIT 1),
  0
)
WHERE event_state IS NULL;
```

When inserting records and `id` field is yet unknown we have (at least) two options:

- if you insert records one by one, calculate `event_state` value in your code (before inserting) depending on values of `start_event` and `stop_event`, and insert with `event_state` as NULL if both values are 0. In this case you'll need to UPDATE the record right after the INSERT by fetching the state of "most recent preceding one":

```sql
INSERT INTO table1 (start_event, stop_event, event_state)
VALUES (?, ?, ?);
```

...and if `event_state` inserted as NULL:

```sql
UPDATE table1
SET event_state = COALESCE(
  (SELECT t1.event_state
  FROM table1 t1
  WHERE t1.id < LAST_INSERT_ID() AND t1.event_state IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY t1.id DESC
  LIMIT 1),
  0
)
WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

- if you insert records by batches, you can use triggers:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER correct_event_state
BEFORE INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.event_state = IF(
  NEW.event_state IS NULL,
  COALESCE(
    (SELECT t1.event_state
    FROM table1 t1
    WHERE t1.id < NEW.id AND t1.event_state IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY t1.id DESC
    LIMIT 1),
    0
  ),
  NEW.event_state
);
```

By the way, since records with higher `id` depend on records with lower `id`, better insert records in the ascending order:

```sql
INSERT INTO `table1`
VALUES
  (1, 0, 0, null),
  (2, 0, 1, 0),
  (3, 0, 0, null),
  (4, 1, 0, 1),
  (5, 0, 0, null),
  (6, 0, 0, null),
  (7, 0, 0, null),
  (8, 0, 1, 0),
  (9, 0, 0, null),
  (10, 0, 1, 0);
```

Here you don't need to run updates after you insert the records, since NULL values in `event_state` field retrieve it from the previous non-NULL record.

Here is how you need to define the primary key:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
    `id` BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `start_event` BIT,
    `stop_event` BIT,
    `event_state` BIT
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solving this problem is surprisingly easy. Here's a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46fa24/1)

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN stop_event = 1 THEN 0
            WHEN start_event = 1 THEN 1
       ELSE NULL END current_state
  FROM table1
 WHERE start_event = 1 OR stop_event = 1
 ORDER BY id DESC
 LIMIT 1;
```

This retrieves the most recent (that is, largest `id` value) row from the table that doesn't mean "the same as the previous event_state". The CASE / WHEN / THEN clause implements  your rules for getting the current state.

Comment: This would retrieve the event_state for the most recent row (with the highest `id`).  So to populate the entire `event_state` column, we could indeed LEFT OUTER JOIN to your query and join on `id`.  You'd also need to add a WHERE to avoid considering ids higher than the "current" one though.  Which would make this solution very similar to my `Solution 3`.

Comment: If I understand the requirement, the "previous" state only comes into play for rows excluded by `WHERE start_event = 1 OR stop_event = 1`. Otherwise the most recent row (largest `id` value) stands alone to determine the result. So just excluding the rows from the sorted and limited result set does the trick. (But I might not understand the requirement.)